# how to set kafka consumer concurrency using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am writing a Java based Kafka Consumer application. I am utilizing kafka-clients, Spring Kafka and Spring boot for my application. While Spring boot lets me easily write Kafka Consumers (without really writing the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, ConsumerFactory etc), I want to be able to define / customize some of the properties for these consumers. However, I could not find out an easy way to do it using Spring boot. For eg: some of the properties that I would be interested in setting up are -

`ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG`
`ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG`

I took a look at the Spring Boot pre-defined properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Also, based on an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051768/how-to-write-kafka-consumers-single-threaded-vs-multi-threaded), I want to setup the concurrency on the consumers, but cannot find a configuration, application.properties driven way to do that using Spring Boot.

An obvious way is to define the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, ConsumerFactory` classes again in my Spring Context and work from there. I wanted to understand if there is a cleaner way of doing that, especially since I am using Spring Boot.

Versions-

- kafka-clients - 0.10.0.0-SASL
- spring-kafka - 1.1.0.RELEASE
- spring boot - 1.5.10.RELEASE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the URL you cited, scroll down to

```
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency= # Number of threads to run in the listener containers.
```

> spring-kafka - 1.1.0.RELEASE

I recommend upgrading to at least 1.3.5; it has a much simpler threading model, thanks to KIP-62.

**EDIT**

With Boot 2.0, you can set arbitrary producer, consumer, admin, common properties, as described [in the boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka-extra-props).

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.heartbeat.interval.ms
```

With Boot 1.5 there is only `spring.kafka.properties` as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.13.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka-extra-props).

This sets the properties for both producers and consumers, but you may see some noise in the log about unused/unsupported properties for the producer.

Alternatively, you can simply override Boot's consumer factory and add properties as needed...

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> kafkaConsumerFactory(KafkaProperties properties) {
    Map<String, Object> consumerProps = properties.buildConsumerProperties();
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 5_000);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Object>(consumerProps);
}
```

Comment: ahh, thanks for the concurrency property, Gary! However, can you shed light on how can I **configure properties that are not supported by Spring Boot ?** I tried to initialize a `ConsumerConfig` with some prop from application.properties and some defined through code, but that approach is not working. As for bumping up the release, I am dependent on kafka-clients release, since our broker supports that release. Because of that I have to utilize the above versions as per the compatibility matrix - http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/#quick-start

Comment: See the edit to my answer. Regardless, I strongly urge you to upgrade to a newer kafka-clients (and spring-kafka 1.3.5). Thanks to [KIP-35](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-35+-+Retrieving+protocol+version) newer clients can talk to older brokers, as long as you don't try to use features the broker doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

I googled for it and found https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/604. The issue had been closed citing https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka-extra-props. But is for spring boot version 2.0.